# Fire an event on specific html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm creating input html element with jQuery with following event handlers like so:

```
$("<input type=\"text\" />").
   focus(function()
   {
      //do something on focus
   })
   .blur(function()
   {
      //do something on blur
   });
```

If I have two such inputs on one page and I have focus on one and then I click to focus on another, only focus handler executes but not blur. [You can try this here](http://jsfiddle.net/developer830/9JtLq/4/).  What needs to happen is focus handler on one input gets executed and blur on another.

Comment: Is the "<" character in your selector a typo?

Comment: its not a typo, this is a way to create html element in jQuery. there is a more complete example if you follow the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens, is the blur is called, but immediately after, the focus of the other event is called, overwriting the "blur" message.